# How to apply function to colnames in tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Just like in title: is there any function that allows applying another function to column names of `data frame`? I mean something like `forcats::fct_relabel` that applies some function to factor labels.

To give an example, supose I have a `data.frame` as below:

```
X<-data.frame(
   firababst = c(1,1,1),
   secababond = c(2,2,2),
   thiababrd = c(3,3,3)
 )  

X
  firababst secababond thiababrd
1         1          2         3
2         1          2         3
3         1          2         3
```

Now I wish to get rid of `abab` from column names by applying `stringr::str_remove`. My workaround involves `magrittr::set_colnames`:

```
 X %>% 
   set_colnames(colnames(.) %>% str_remove('abab'))
  first second third
1     1      2     3
2     1      2     3
3     1      2     3
```

Can you suggest some more strightforward way? Ideally, something like:

```
X %>% 
   magic_foo(str_remove, 'abab')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
X %>%
 rename_all(~ str_remove(., "abab"))

  first second third
1     1      2     3
2     1      2     3
3     1      2     3
```

Comment: OMG! So easy! even `X %>% rename_all(str_remove, 'abab')` works!

Comment: Yes, even that is an option :)

Answer (score 0):

With `base R`, we can do

```
names(X) <- sub("abab", "", names(X))
```